# how to check wheather the given normed sequence is finite or not

Tags: normed-spaces

Does the sequence 
$$
(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 8},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}},...)
$$
have finite $\ell^2$ norm?
I
have tried this problem using the definition of $\ell^2$ space. 
Is it right to continue in this way?
If not, tell me how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the definition of the $\ell^2$ norm, the norm of the sequence is
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} \right)^2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-1} < \infty
$$
as it is comparable to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.